# How to Convert Horizontal List into Vertical List and Count the Term in Python

Tags: python, list

I Have a dataframe like this.

```
[car, time, door]
[tv, radio, car]
```

and how to flip the dataframe into like this.

```
car    2
time   1
door   1
tv     1
radio  1
```

Thanks.

I appreciate you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dataframe like this:

```py
                col1
0  [car, time, door]
1   [tv, radio, car]
```

Then:

```py
x = df.explode("col1").value_counts()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
col1 
car      2
door     1
radio    1
time     1
tv       1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong:
You need to convert a list of lists into a dictionary keeping track of how many times an object occurs.
Here:

```py
data = [["car", "time", "door"],["tv", "radio", "car"]]
new_dict = {}

for i in data:
    for n in i:
        if n in new_dict:
            #Adds if exists in dictionary
            new_dict[n] = new_dict[n]+1
        else:
            #Creates if doesnt exists in dictionary
            new_dict[n] = 0
print(new_dict)
```